# How to connect a Rails App with Google Plus account and fetch the logged in and connected user's activities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any gem or method through which I can connect to Rails App. And after connecting to Google plus ,users activities can be shown on my app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a [RESTful API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) to access read-only data from Google+ profiles. If it covers your needs you can use it via [RESTClient](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) or [ActiveResource](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596521424/activeresource_id59243.html).

Comment: But How will i get the User Profile Id ?

Comment: I'd suggest using the OmniAuth gem https://github.com/intridea/omniauth to link accounts on your site with the IDs on Google+ - here's a pointer on how to do so http://hoisie.com/2011/09/12/using-google-oauth-with-omniauth/

Comment: I tried this approach,but always I am getting the email id at the param uid. And I need the numerical ID (profile id,used to access the google plus for a particular user).As I think.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I recently wrote a tutorial on authenticating users with Google plus on a Rails app. It doesn't cover profile activities, but it shows the basic idea of getting profile data and connecting it with your back-end. You can extend it further from there.

Here is the link: http://devinyoungweb.com/google-plus-sign-in-with-ruby-on-rails/